# Best practice for indicating sources

Tags: discussion

Is there a best practice for giving sources after definitions, etc. (in posts)?

I've typically just added a "from New Oxford American Dictionary" at the bottom but was wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine. In fact, if you're really in a hurry, just type `(NOAD)`—it's on our [list of abbreviations](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie).

Another option would be
`<sub>([source: NOAD](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/147/))</sub>`,
 which produces the following (a smaller typeface and a link to the abbreviation list):

<sub>([source: NOAD](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/147/))</sub>