# What does "NARQ" means?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of common abbreviations (NOAD, ESL, PIE…)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie)

I've seen "NARQ" in the below topic.
But I cannot understand the meaning.

[https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89740/how-do-you-disambiguate-phrases-like-killing-doctors-when-you-cant-use-an-art#*=*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89740/how-do-you-disambiguate-phrases-like-killing-doctors-when-you-cant-use-an-art#_=_)

> I think it's NARQ.

Is it an abbreviated word?

Comment: It stands for Not A Real Question. Common on ELU, obviously, but not well-known to the world at large.

Comment: "NARQ" is a transcription of the cry of the well-known _Regged wight_, a unique type of owl that can often be found in these parts.  The cry of "NARQ" is usually heard before some form of action by the aforementioned owl, such as a migration; or more frequently, the closure of a question.

Comment: So that's what [Regdwight](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwigh)'s username means.