# New abbreviation for Oxford Dictionaries?

Tags: discussion

Oxford Dictionaries Online has had a major site revamp. Since its brand name is simply "Oxford Dicationaries" (not Oxford Dictionaries *Online*) and its URL is https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/, I suggest that our FAQ entry containing the list of accepted abbreviations be updated to reflect this. In particular, I suggest that we drop the trailing *O* in *ODO*.

Although the FAQ is maintained as a community wiki and hence freely editable, freely editing it without community support can easily become messy. I'm therefore raising this as a meta question for support.

- FAQ: [List of common abbreviations and acronyms (NOAD, ESL, PIE...)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-and-acronyms-noad-esl-pie)
- Current entry: *ODO — Oxford Dictionaries Online (now "Oxford Living Dictionaries")*
- Suggested entry: *OD — Oxford Dictionaries (former names: "Oxford Dictionaries Online" and "Oxford Living Dictionaries"; both were listed under the abbreviation "ODO")*

If you support the change to *OD*, up-vote this question. If you prefer to leave it as *ODO*, down-vote this question.

Comment: I upvoted, but am personally of the opinion that any abbreviations used should be spelled out at first occurrence in a question-answer set.

Comment: I am voting against this in part because the proper abbreviation for the present name really is O.L.D. for "Oxford Living Dictionaries" (there's no reason to add O.D. too),  and in part because that entry is too verbose: I prefer a list entry to have fewer lines if possible for quicker reading. However, having said that, I think this meta thread is too deferential for a community wiki post. It's made to be community wiki specifically so it can be easy to edit without consultation. Just do it and if somebody else dislikes it, they can roll it back or change it to something they think is better.

Comment: You're suggesting these abbreviations, but are they what Oxford and others use for the new abbreviations? Anyway, keep the old abbreviations _and_ add the new abbreviations, right?

Comment: @JEL Thanks. In dictionary citations, as opposed to Q&A *about* the dictionary, the abbreviation may only occur once, as the anchor word for the link to the dictionary entry. I'm quite happy to use just the abbreviation in those situations for standard references, but would often include author and title for other references. Note that even in scholarly works (at least in my field of Computer Science), citations regularly employ standard abbreviations.

Comment: @Tonepoet Hmm, the word 'living' isn't in the title on the page I linked to, though it does appear after selecting the language. About being too deferential, I disagree. I'm proposing a change to a FAQ for a widely-used standard abbreviation. I'd rather have the full discussion here and even have this meta question eventually discarded than to have the FAQ rolled back.

Comment: @Mitch That's a good point. In the text used for their [legal notice](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/privacy-policy), [licensing](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/licensing-and-developers) and [help](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/help) pages, they use abbreviations for the parent entity (OUP, Oxford University Press) and The OED, but not Oxford Dictionaries. ...

Comment: @Mitch ... I found a [reference to ODO](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/august-2013-update/) in their blog, dated 28 August 2013. Interestingly, it refers to "*OxfordDictionaries.com Online (ODO)*", and not just "Oxford Dictionaries Online" as we have it in our FAQ. Unless there's compelling reason otherwise, I'll take this as an authoritative reference and leave the abbreviation as it stands.

Comment: @Mitch About your last question - it's now moot in light of my previous comment. I didn't have a strong opinion either way, but if the existing entry was simply amended, I would have preferred to leave a note about the previous abbreviation.

Comment: I can't be accused of putting my opinion on how it *should* be done ("abbreviations used should be spelled out") into practice consistently, so I won't hesitate to say that comparing ELU to a scholarly work is misleading. My concern is rather selfish: I don't like encountering abbreviations I need to look up when a few extra keystrokes on the part of the author could've spared me the research effort. For citations, if the source provides a citation (as is the case with *The Free Dictionary* and *Oxford English Dictionary*, for examples) I feel it is owed to the source to respect their desire.

Comment: Whoa dude... you just answered your own question _in_ your question, and at the top of your question, _and_ the reverse of what you suggest later in the question. That's messed up. So those who voted on your question, should they come back and reverse their vote? Very confusing. If you must, remove your edit and put it as an alternative answer. Also your edit doesn't seem coherent with respect to time; aren't you trying to get what the abbreviation should be _today_ based on name changes at Oxford within the past few months? I'm so confused by all your time references.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks again. Good recommendation, and yes, I was wondering about the timing as well, though the URL seems to have remained constant during that time. I'll change my update to an answer.

Comment: Why do we need an abbreviation in the first place when you can spend a few more seconds to type the whole phrase? I really don't understand the reason to abbreviate whatever is used on English Language and Usage. A long time user (3+ years) here doesn't even know what MSE is. I have used "Oxford Online Dictionary" for the last 13 months and nobody complained about it. The best abbreviation I see is OLD and I don't like it.

Comment: @Rathony Interesting question. It depends on the context and intent. Here's one rationale: in English at least, the space occupied by a piece of text in relation to nearby pieces of text can serve as a form of highlighting. When quoting dictionary definitions, the definition is usually of more interest than the source. Using an abbreviation allows the citation to be visually smaller.

Answer (score 9):

**Changing the abbreviation from *ODO* to *OD* would invalidate existing answers,** and the list is intended to help people interpret existing answers, not just assist in creating new answers.

Any change has to be "backwards-compatible".

That's why in the most recent revision I maintained *ODO* as the abbreviation for the online Oxford Dictionaries at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com. Incidentally, calling "Oxford Living Dictionaries" a "former" name as in your suggestion is [incorrect](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/).

Cross-referencing with the pre-existing Oxford dictionary with *L* in its abbreviation helps avert confusion in choosing the abbreviation to use.

Even if *OD* were accepted as an abbreviation, *ODO* would still need to appear, **and** the differentiation for "Oxford Living Dictionary" would also still be needed. It creates an extra level of complexity.

It may be possible to lay out the list more clearly, although I don't think it's exactly unclear now.

While you're right that "freely editing it without community support can easily become messy," I don't believe the change I made, keeping *ODO* for the dictionary's new persona and disambiguating a potential confusion, was actually a substantive change. Currently the list reflects the status quo and has not introduced anything new.

While I made the latest change, and so naturally I support its current content, I'm not averse to improvement. But improvement must not invalidate existing answers or make the list useless in interpreting existing answers; nor should it introduce unnecessary complexity. I do not support the introduction of *OD* (and have voted on the question accordingly — this answer explains why I did that).

Comment: I agree with most of the things suggested here as indicated by my comment, plus the fact that O.D.O. needs to be referenced for the sake of any unedited older answers, but to be fair, the proposal under consideration does not suggest removing reference to O.D.O., so that should not be a factor when deciding whether we should accept the change presently proposed or not.

Comment: The landing page I linked to doesn't include the word 'living' as part of the dictionary's title, though it does appear after selecting English. Since the dictionary's name changed, we would be creating a new abbreviation for a new name. This doesn't invalidate previous answers - they still refer to the old name. Nevertheless, I've since found a blog using ODO to refer to the current dictionary (see [this comment](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/new-abbreviation-for-oxford-dictionaries?noredirect=1#comment37442_9586)), so I'm satisfied with keeping *ODO*.

Comment: Why couldn't we simply revise *ODO* to mean *Oxford dictionaries online* instead of *Oxford DIctionaries Online*? Similar changes have worked pretty well for GSM and GPO and others.

Answer (score 3):

(Based on a [comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/new-abbreviation-for-oxfords-dictionaries?noredirect=1#comment37442_9586))

I found a [reference to ODO](https://web.archive.org/web/20190503234158/http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/august-2013-update/) in the dictionary's blog, dated 28 August 2013. Interestingly, it refers to "OxfordDictionaries.com Online (ODO)", not "Oxford Dictionaries Online" as we have it in our FAQ. Unless there's compelling reason otherwise, I'll take this as an authoritative reference and leave the abbreviation as it stands.

Although the time of this blog predates the recent dictionary 'refresh', the domain name has remained the same. The domain name was one of two justifications for changing the abbreviation, the other being the name displayed on the dictionary's landing page.